# Notification when certain time reached android

Tags: java, android, xml, notifications

What I want is that user get time through time picker let say 18:00, and this time got displayed on screen, when this time got reached I just want to give notification to user noting else.

Comment: Maybe you could use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use a service that starts a Timer to check if the hours that the user has chosen have already been exceeded. You can save in a simple SQLite table and within that Timer you check user hours vs System hours, x in x time

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current time. Therefore, you can have the app running in the background checking if the chosen time is equal to the current time. I can't suggest how to structure this however due to not having the code for the program.